# Calendar REST API in Office 365 APIs Preview - not all events

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

I am building a JS Webapp with the new Office 365 REST Api. My problem is, that I am no getting all occurence events from a Roomcalendar.

Has anybody an Idea?

I am trying to receive all Events with this URL:
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users(room@exampledomain.com)/Events?$top=100&$filter=End%20ge%202014-08-20T22:30:00Z%20and%20Start%20le%202020-12-14T22:30:00Z

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server will page the results back to you in lots of 100 (AFIAK), your date range is quite large 2014-2020 if you have Recurring appointments with no End date your more then likely going to get pages of results. Check the Results you getting back for @odata.nextLink eg

"@odata.nextLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('user@domain.onmicrosoft.com')/Events/?%24top=100&%24filter=End+ge+2014-08-20T22%3a30%3a00Z+and+Start+le+2020-12-14T22%3a30%3a00Z&%24skip=100"

This is what you should use to the get the next page of results

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Hmm thats not exactly what i am searching for. I just need the next 100 meetings with all occurences. How could i solve this?

Comment: If your missing something in the results what is it specifically your missing that you are expecting to be returned ?

Comment: Was my bad. Everything is there, but could it be possible that $orderby=Start is not working?

Comment: Yeah I can't get $orderby to work either it just ignores whatever I enter.

Comment: Thanks that was everything I wanted to know. 
I solved it by selecting a minor range and getting more results to avoid the paging.